# Bash script Sort the text files in directory and export data into csv

Tags: bash, csv, export-to-csv

I have 45 directories in my drive with naming format Sub1,Sub2..Sub45 each consists of more than 300 text files, all text files in each directory have same naming format

```
regional_vol_GM1.txt
regional_vol_GM2.txt
regional_vol_GM*.txt
```

I would like to sort the directories and text files in each directory in sequential order and export the data in each file into csv file,

Following is the script that i have written

```
    eval "dirs=($(ls -v --quoting-style=shell-always))"
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
  eval "files=($(
    ls -vd --quoting-style=shell-always -- "$dir"/t1/regional_vol*.txt))"
  tail -q -n 1 -- "${files[@]}" | paste -sd , -
done > data.csv
```

Now i would like to remodel my output csv file with file name of text file as row value and directory name as column, since every directory has 300 text files with same naming format, i just need one single row with file name as header and directory name as column in csv file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a `/` in `x` and thus in your expression. Change your `sed` separator by something not likely to occur in `x`, like:

```
sed -i "1s#^#${x}\n#" ${x}
```

and to change "in-place", just enable the `-i` option (if not available in your system, use a temp file and move back to the original file)

Now for your file sort: the problem is that wildcard matching or even `ls` sorts the files but using alphabetical order so `regional_vol_GM2.txt` comes *after* `regional_vol_GM100.txt`.

So even if it's a bit of a hack you could replace this:

```
tail -q -n 1 "$dir"/t1/regional_vol*.txt
```

by this:

```
tail -q -n 1 (cd "$dir"/t1;ls -C1 regional_vol_GM*.txt | sort -k2 -tM -n)
```

Why it works:

- I'm using the numerical mode of `sort`, using second field, delimited by `M` (the digits come after `_GM`).

Why it's a hack:

- it relies on the output of `ls` which is generally frowned upon. Here it's a simple ls on 1 column, no spaces in your names, should be OK
- it has to perform a `cd` just in case there's a `M` in the directory path and the sort would find the wrong field

What you should do to simply fix that:

- you should generate your files/ask the people who do to do it with zero padding: 1 becomes 001, 2 becomes 002, etc. so alphanumerical sorting works, no need to do the complex `sort` hack.

Comment: The sed command also fails to actually change the file, maybe address that as well?

Comment: Yes the sed command does not work, i am still getting wrong output , instead of values from directory 1, i am getting values from directory 100

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre , Its works, but there is a problem, since i have 45 directories, the directories are not sorted sequentially, Sorry for rephrasing my question again, i need to sort both directories and files inside the directories and arrange them in sequential order and export the data in each directory to csv

Comment: don't you have like _a lot_ of duplicate info in your .csv file? because I thinkg that the `paste` command shouldn't be inside the loop. and the sort problem is because of alphanumerical sort vs numerical sort. I think I can fix it but first answer my first question.

Comment: Yes paste command should be outside of loop ,i have changed that , i recognized the mistake

Comment: good. Could you tell us more about the name of your directories.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I have got it, i made those changes and i am reposting the code now, but i have some other issues, i would like to get file name of each file in first row of csv file and directory name as column, [this is my desired output](http://imgur.com/vwr39vb). Since all directories have same file names, i just need one row and underneath that corresponding values of each text file will be written with column being corresponding directory : The Directory name is : Sub1,Sub2 ,Sub3...Sub45, I have edited changes in code that i made

Comment: you shouldn't have heavily edited your question, now my answer on `sed` makes no sense... Maybe you could revert back to the previous version and post another question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128973/discussion-between-devandevak-and-jean-francois-fabre).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I solved my issue, your help is all that i need, brilliant , thanks for your suggestions, greatly helpful

Comment: you're welcome. next time remember not to edit your question too much (first time was okay with the paste out of the loop) so the answer matches completely.